# Griddle_React default css

Tags: reactjs, griddle

I am using griddle-react and have issues with default styling css i.e. 'griddle-cell' or 'griddle-row'. Where do I find/install corresponding css ? Or am I supposed to create myself ?

```
<Griddle styleConfig={styleConfig}
            data={...}
            plugins={[plugins.LocalPlugin]}
/>
```

and

```
const styleConfig = {        
    classNames: {
        Cell: 'griddle-cell',
        Row: 'griddle-row', //'row-class',   
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why the `c` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Griddle 1.x does not ship with a default stylesheet, just [default class names](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/blob/3466e7cc19f0f5fba591dcf487ec7d5abec39e86/src/index.js#L34-L53).

As of around v1.8 (via [Griddle#677](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/pull/677)) it does include an incomplete `LegacyStylePlugin` that we'd love to align more closely with how Griddle 0.x rendered, if you care to contribute.